# How do I input a vector in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How can I write this expression into Wolfram Alpha?

[image]

I have read the vector examples page on Wolfram Alpha's homepage, but I didn't know which method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to break the one vector equation into two one dimensional equations.

you have above in one dimensional Wolfram Alpha would be

> a + (0.5b) +(x*(-a - (0.5*b)))

so if you let vector a = {i,j} and vector b = {k,l} you get the above equation

The equation would therfore be typed in

> [vector {i + (0.5*k) + (x*(-i - (0.5*k))),j + (0.5*l) + (x*(-j - (0.5*l)))}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector%20%7Bi%20%2B%20(0.5*k)%20%2B%20(x*(-i%20-%20(0.5*k))),j%20%2B%20(0.5*l)%20%2B%20(x*(-j%20-%20(0.5*l)))%7D)

Comment: @N.JAbel If this answer was helpful, consider making it the accepted answer.